# Can someone help me with Ruby regex to check any word with letters starting with t and ending with r and replace with word Twitter? Thank you

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me with Ruby regex to check any word with letters starting with t and ending with r and replace with word Twitter? Thank you

Comment: `"My teacher has a house with a tar and gravel roof".gsub(/\bt[a-z]*r\b/i, 'Twitter') #=> "My Twitter has a house with a Twitter and gravel roof"`. Without the word-breaks (`\b`) we might get something like this: `"My teacher has a house with a starry and gravel roof".gsub(/t[a-z]*r/i, 'Twitter') #=> "My Twitter has a house with a sTwittery and gravel roof"`.

Answer (score 1):

I find that [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) is very useful for working out how regexes work in Ruby.

You have two questions here. First, what regex will recognise what you want. Second, how to replace that found string with something else.

1. Your regex will be something like `/\bt\w*r\b/`. The elements here are `\b`, which is a word boundary. Then, we have the letter `t`, then any number of word characters `\w*`, then the letter `r`, and finally another word boundary `\b`. (Without the word-boundary characters, your regex will find `t...r` inside other words, too, so will work on things like 'stress', 'stirs' etc.
2. To do the replacement you want the `gsub` method.

```rb
new_string = your_string.gsub(/\bt\w*r\b/i, 'Twitter')
```

This will substitute the string `Twitter` for the found regex. The `i` on the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive - omit this if you want it to only find the lower-case text as in the regex.

Comment: A "word character" `\w` is any letter **or number, or underscore**. So just beware, if you use `\w` instead of a more concise `[a-z]`, then this will also match e.g. `"t123_456r"`.

Comment: You should also bear in mind that using [a-z] may cause problems with hyphenated words, for example. Generally, the `\w` regex is more likely to give the right results for the beginner.

Comment: And, if you're happy with this answer, Bibek, it'd be great if you accepted it.

Comment: @TomLord And `[a-z]` doesn't recognize non-ASCII things like `éclair` so you might want to move all the way to one of the [Unicode-aware `\p{...}` patterns](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).